# Spread operator ... copying state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pagination, react-context

I'm using pagination and I need to add after page iteration new data to state.
Using context for storing my data.

**function for fetching data**

```
const fetchMissions = (dispatch) => async (page) => {
  const response = await fdApi.get('/mission', {
    params: { page, limit: 10 },
  });
  dispatch({ type: 'fetch_missions', payload: response.data });
};
```

**Reducer**

```
const missionReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add_error':
      return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
    case 'fetch_missions':
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Problem is in reducer case 'fetch_missions', no idea how to persist old data when fetching new page and add new data to same array

[Output from my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ianXj.png)

Comment: What is the structure of `state`?

Comment: @Matt Ideally it would be   missions: {
      data: [],
      pageInfo: {}
    },

Answer (score 0):

Use need to modify your reducer, Assuming your state is like `{missions: []}`. Make sure your initial missions in state is empty array

```
case 'fetch_missions':
      return {missions: [...state.missions, ...action.payload.missions.docs]}
```

Comment: Invalid JS and `action.payload.missions` is an object in OP's example data

Comment: @Matt is correct, `{state.missions: []}` isn't a valid way to assign an object property. You probably just meant to do `{missions:`?

Comment: yes sorry, I didnt saw that, check this {missions: [...state.missions, ...action.payload.missions.docs]}

Comment: Still not quite right I don't think, `{ ...state, missions: [...state.missions, ...action.payload.missions.docs]}` and that assumes you've got the correct structure of `state`

Comment: He need to make sure the structure is correct of the state. the above is just to show how he can use it

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your reducer to have this code:

```
// Setup the initial state of the reducer to have empty arrays or null for all values
const initialState = {
    errorMessage: null,
    missions: {
        data: [],
        pageInfo: {},
    }
};
const missionReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add_error':
      return { ...state, errorMessage: action.payload };
    case 'fetch_missions':
      return {
        ...state,
        missions: { ...missions, data: [...missions.data, ...action.payload.missions.docs] } 
     };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```